# SQL, How to convert VARCHAR to bigint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field that is `VARCHAR(6)` I am trying to insert it into another table of type `bigint`  it is giving me an error

(Error Converting from data type varchar to bigint

here is what i am doing

```
CONVERT(bigint, seconds) as seconds
```

Can anybody help with this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the data to make sure that the values in the field you're converting are actually convertible to int?

Comment: seems that one of your varchar is not convertible...

Comment: I have it either have a null, -number and positive number! but i did isnull(second, 0)  and i still have the same issue

Convert(bigint, ISNULL(ts.TimeInSeconds,0)  ) AS seconds

Comment: try to find it with a `where isnumeric(seconds) = 0`

Comment: isnumeric(seconds) = 0 did not help but gave me an idea and it worked.
 Convert(bigint, isnumiric(ts.TimeInSeconds) ) AS second


Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is the answer

```
(CASE
  WHEN
    (isnumeric(ts.TimeInSeconds) = 1) 
  THEN
    CAST(ts.TimeInSeconds AS bigint)
  ELSE
    0
  END) AS seconds
```

Comment: Might want to edit this to be correct, as `isnumiric` won't exist (check spelling).  Also, even though `CONVERT()` (and `ISNUMERIC()`) works on your machine, you've tagged your question as 'sql', which is a _language_ - your machine has a particular _implementation_ (SQL Server).  The standard is `CAST(... as BIGINT)` - for future viewers, it may be best to either tag your question with the relevant RDBMS, or write a 'standards' version.

Comment: So what you wanted was to insert a `1` if the value in `TimeInSeconds` is a valid integer and `0` if it is not a valid integer? Don't you want the value in column `TimeInSeconds` inserted somewhere?

Comment: I have corrected my answer after figuring out the problem. Thanks again for your help guys :)

Answer (score 8):

an alternative would be to do something like:

```
SELECT
   CAST(P0.seconds as bigint) as seconds
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      seconds
   FROM
      TableName
   WHERE
      ISNUMERIC(seconds) = 1
   ) P0
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your code is right. If you run the following code it converts the string '60' which is treated as varchar and it returns integer 60, if there is integer containing string in second it works.

```
select CONVERT(bigint,'60') as seconds
```

and it returns

```
60
```

Answer (score -1):

A wrinkle on this problem occurs when the text 'number' has a decimal point, at least in TSQL, that causes the solution above to not work.

Just posting in case it might help others. Drove me crazy for an hour.
A solution seems to be to first converting to float and then to bigint.

select cast(1234567891011.0 as varchar(50)) as numb1 into #t1;
select * from #t1;

select numb1
,cast(numb1 as bigint) as numb1x
from #t1; --Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

--Even though it is a number:
select numb1
,isnumeric(numb1) as isnumb
from #t1;

--proposed solution above fails:
select numb1,
CASE WHEN isnumeric(numb1)=1 then cast(numb1 as bigint)
ELSE 0
END as numb1x
from #t1;
--Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

--works:
select numb1
,cast(cast(numb1 as float) as bigint) as numb1x
from #t1;